# Interchanging $\sum$ and $\int$ in a calculation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, orthogonal-polynomials

In an article they swapped the signs $\int$ and $\sum$ as follows

\begin{align*} S_{n}(\xi,x)&= (-1)^{n+1}\Big(\frac{d}{dx}\Big)^{n}\Big[\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\int^{\infty}_{0}e^{-(j-n-\xi)t}L_{j}(x)dt\Big], \quad Re(\xi)<-n\\&=(-1)^{n+1}\Big(\frac{d}{dx}\Big)^{n} \int^{\infty}_{0}\Big[ \sum^{\infty}_{j=0}e^{-(j-n-\xi)t}L_{j}(x)dt\Big]   \end{align*}

where $(L_{j})$  are the Laguerre polynomials of order zero.

See page 5 of [this article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.1287640) for the full reference/context.

Who can tell me why?

Comment: Just to clarify the first sentence: *"In an article we swapped"*: does that imply it's an article of which you are one of the authors?

Comment: I do not speak English well, I used a software for the translation;I would say they have changed $\sum$ and $\int$

Comment: Fair enough -- that seemed a bit odd.

Comment: You speak of the intervesrion?

Comment: No, the phrasing. For the interversion, I'd bet on something like uniform convergence.

Comment: see page 5  of the link http://sci-hub.bz/10.1063/1.1287640

Comment: If $\int \sum_n |f_n(x)| dx$ or $\sum_n \int |f_n(x)| dx$ are finite then $\int \sum_n f_n(x) dx = \sum_n \int f_n(x) dx$. This is a special case of the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.

Comment: Yes, In this case it is not applicable

Comment: Can you prove it? Without Fubini-Tonelli most interchanges are not justified.

Comment: So take irrelevant parameters out of the problem: you have $\sum_{j=0}^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-jt} A_j dt$ where $|A_j|$ is less than a constant (depending on $x$ but nothing else) divided by $j!$. That division by $j!$ seems to save the day, if I'm not missing something.

Comment: Oh, I see the problem, $C_x$ probably doesn't exist...so you need to know something about the behavior of $L_j(x)$ as $j \to \infty$.

Comment: I think that they have used this result $\sum^{\infty}_{j=0} f_{j}(x)= F(x)$ in the distributional sense then, 
$\int^{\infty}_{0} \sum^{\infty}_{j=0} f_{j}(x) dx = \sum^{\infty}_{j=0} \int^{\infty}_{0} f_{j}(x) dx =  \int^{\infty}_{0} F(x) dx$. Is it correct? see page 5